# Show only user created tables in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, metadata, information-schema

Is there a SQL command by which I can display only the tables created by users and excluding those present by default in the MySQL database?

Comment: do you have a user table? or do you mean a User in the database?

Comment: Um..When I say "users"..it's really just me,the root-user..And yes,I have privileges to change the database. I've created some tables and I want to see just those..rather than tables like : "general_log","help_category" etc..which existed when I created the database in the first place i.e installed mysql..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This about wraps it up:

```
select * from information_schema.tables 
where table_schema not in ('information_schema', 'mysql', 'performance_schema')
```

The `information_schema` contains meta-information about your database. You can list all tables using `information_schema.tables`. If you exclude the two meta-schemas `information_schema`, and `mysql`, you'll get all user-tables

Comment: The table_schema for all MY tables is "mysql" ! ..So,this command just returns an empty set :(

Comment: An obvious solution for me seems to be that I can create another database and copy all the tables I need,from the MySQL database to the newly created one. But that wont solve THIS problem,will it..

Comment: Aaah, you shouldn't put your tables in a system-schema. Then I can't help you. Read the documentation for MySQL's system-schemata to find out which ones are yours and which ones aren't...

Comment: If there isn't an alternative, I suppose I'll have to resort to that :)

Comment: You should! :-) I don't think you should create your own tables in a system-schema. I'm surprised, MySQL even allows you to do it...

Comment: Oddly enough,it does :) And I've never felt the necessity to create tables in a different database before now! But I'll keep this in mind henceforth.

Comment: Yeah... There are lots of things that could go wrong if you have user tables in that schema. e.g. you occupy a name that will be used by MySQL 6.0 (or whatever future version)...